# Why don't float operations work properly?

Tags: c

I'm new to C, but i have previously coded in C++ and C#. I have written this code as an assignment, but the float operations don't work properly. What it's supposed to do is, by entering two positive integers, n and m, the end result should be this [a sum of a sum with n and the square root of a multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGfuf.png).

My problem is that, even though the first sum works, both the multiplication and the square root (and in the end the final sum) don't work. In the end, whatever two numbers n and m i write, the sum will be ok and the other two will be completely innaccurate - either 1, both the multiplication and the final sum, or something that makes no sense (to be precise, "1.#INF00").

This is the code i have written. Does anybody know what i did wrong, or how can I fix this?

```
float sum(int n)
{
    float s = 0;
    for(float i = 1; i<=(float)n; i++)
    {
        s += (2*i)/(3*i*i+4);
    }
    return s;
}

float multiplication(int m)
{
    float p = 1;
    for(float j = 1; j <= (float)m; j++)
    {
        p *= (float)(j*j+1);
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int m;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    scanf("%i", &m);
    float s = sum(&n);
    float p = multiplication(&m);
    float e = s + (float)sqrt(p);
    printf("The sum is %f \n", s);
    printf("The multiplication is %f \n", p);
    printf("The final expression is %f \n", e);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sum(&n)` → expected?

Comment: You should read the warnings from your compiler. They will tell you a lot in this case.

Comment: `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sum’ makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Comment: You say that you have coded C++. Didn't you read your warnings then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the integer values, not pointers, to the functions `sum` and `multiplication`.

```
float sum(int n)
{
    float s = 0;
    for(float i = 1; i<=(float)n; i++)
    {
        s += (2*i)/(3*i*i+4);
    }
    return s;
}

float multiplication(int m)
{
    float p = 1;
    for(float j = 1; j <= (float)m; j++)
    {
        p *= (float)(j*j+1);
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int m;
    scanf("%i", &n);
    scanf("%i", &m);
    float s = sum(n); /* pass an integer, not a pointer */
    float p = multiplication(m); /* pass an integer, not a pointer */
    float e = s + (float)sqrt(p);
    printf("The sum is %f \n", s);
    printf("The multiplication is %f \n", p);
    printf("The final expression is %f \n", e);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```